# Detecting parameter influence

Tags: inference, causality, nonparametric, multivariable

I have a data set consisting of a system's responses to various test configurations. Every test configuration corresponds to a different parameter set. These parameters can have either continuous values or binary values.

I need to figure out which parameters (or which combination) have the most influence upon the system's response. The response is a score between 0-100.

What methods can I use for this statistical analysis?

Comment: I have the same question. My thoughts are: we could use regression analysis. The most simple is linear regression. It can explain what linear combinations of parameters determine the response. If we have some assumptions about type of dependence on parameters we could use the corresponding form of regression equation. Non-linear dependencies demand non-linear regression.